# Cannot find curl-config in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, software-installation, configuration, curl, r

I am installing package RCurl in R and getting an error

```
  checking for curl-config... no
  Cannot find curl-config
  ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
```

I have tried to install libcurl on Ubuntu, but it doesn't solve my problem have some dependecies

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libcurl4-gnutls-dev : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.29.0-1ubuntu3.1) but 7.29.0-1ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
Depends: libldap2-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`locate curl config` gives me nothing:

```
locate curl-config
curl-config
The program 'curl-config' can be found in the following packages:
* libcurl4-gnutls-dev
* libcurl4-nss-dev
* libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

I went through some of the solution [RCurl](http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/FAQ.html) but it is working. Can you suggest or help in this direction. Thank you so much.

**Edit**

when i tried to install(Curl) from Ubuntu Software center got the same erroe message

**Package dependencies cannot be resolved**

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 curl: Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.29.0-1ubuntu3.1) but 7.29.0-1ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
  Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.7.dfsg-13ubuntu2 is to be installed
```

**EDITED**

> sudo aptitude install libcurl4-openssl-dev

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libcurl4-openssl-dev{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,210 kB of archives. After unpacking 2,778 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.29.0-1ubuntu3.1) but 7.29.0-1ubuntu3.2 is installed.
                    Depends: libidn11-dev but it is not going to be installed.
                    Depends: libkrb5-dev but it is not going to be installed.
                    Depends: libldap2-dev but it is not going to be installed.
                    Depends: librtmp-dev but it is not going to be installed.
                    Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed.
 The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
 Keep the following packages at their current version:
 1)     libcurl4-openssl-dev [Not Installed]
```

Comment: Have you tried it with `apt-get install -f`?

Comment: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Also, if you haven't already, take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/356060/dependency-error-installing-curl), it says there might be some conflicts with Google Chrome.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The 3 packages that you found to contain `curl-config`:

1. `libcurl4-gnutls-dev`
2. `libcurl4-nss-dev`
3. `libcurl4-openssl-dev`

All seem to have the same functionality. I installed the first of these via Synaptic Package Manager and was then able to install RCurl from CRAN.

So, if you choose the first option, open a terminal box and do

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

then go into R and do

```
install.packages("RCurl")
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what exactly does your answer mean?

Comment: do sudo liblcurl4-gnutls-dev outside R, in a terminal box. Then install RCurl using install.packages("RCurl") within R.

Comment: I did following and it worked perfectly.
In a new terminal
    sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
In R console
    install.packages("RCurl")

Comment: apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev

Comment: I'll add that only the third `libcurl4-openssl-dev` worked for me on Linux Mint 17.1

Comment: curl expects an SSL/TLS library to already be installed, the 3 packages mentioned are different types of SSL/TLS libraries, for a feature comparison see [this page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/ssl-compared.html)

Comment: I tried the first line and it worked, but then when trying to install swirl to get the other packages installed it failed with openssl, so I received this message:
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)

So I did: 
     sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
and it worked, then I was able install httr, and swirl.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did to solve the same problem:

```
sudo aptitude install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

And when prompted to accept the solution, [Y/n/q]

```
 :
 The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
 Keep the following packages at their current version:
 1)     libcurl4-openssl-dev [Not Installed]      
 :
```

answer "n". Then answer [Y] when another action is prompted.